# Separating C# classes into individual files

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a tool which will split a file containing multiple C# classes, so that each class is in its own file. Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Can't find any, but such a tool is not difficult to build by yourself...

Comment: True, I am considering doing this, but I thought it worth asking as it seems like something that should already be out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are a Resharper (or DevExpress IDE Productivity Tools) user, it has a refactoring that does this. Not sure whether you can have it process the full file as one command, but it's just a couple of keyboard strokes per class, so it can be done manually (unless we are talking hundreds of classes).

Comment: There is Move Type Into Matching Files available in Resharper as project refactoring which do explicitly @haymansfield asks. Here help: Move Types Into Matching Files http://bit.ly/c3xCKE

Comment: @Nick this is one of the most used features of resharper for me. It's hard for me to remember developing without it.

Comment: @Nick +1, but alas I've plumped for CodeRush!

Answer (score 0):

Resharper does this. CodeRush also does this. CodeRush also gives you options to rename the file to match the type, etc.

Comment: I've been using this in Coderush on a singular basis, but does it do it for an entire multiclass file in 1 hit?

Answer (score -1):

Why not cut and paste the classes?  Resharper and other tools (possibly even vs2010) can do a Refactor...Move Class, but it that would probably take longer than:

- Create new file
- Cut class from original file
- Paste to new file

Comment: you could use ctrl+m+o to collapse everything, making the cutting easier :)

Comment: I doubt the author of this post is not aware of copy paste.

Comment: in my case, it's because I'm looking at a generated file that if 5MB big and it would be nice to have a tool which can reliably refactor the code repeatedly.

Comment: Ctrl+M+O is great but only collapses contents on classes. Use Ctrl+M+L (twice if required) to toggle collapsing EVERYTHING. Ctrl+M+M will collapse/expand whatever is in focus.

Comment: Anyway, I guess a tool would be preferred as I expect it would repair all broken references